# Passing alignment tab character to \ifx

Tags: errors, amsmath, conditionals

I have the following macro

```
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand\seq[4] %length, delimiter, generating func, last term
{%
  \def\s##1{\def\n{##1} #3}
  \xintListWithSep{#2}
  {%
    \xintApply{\s}{\xintSeq{1}{#1}}
  }%
  #2\ldots
  \ifx\\#4\\ %if 4th arg empty
    %empty
  \else
    #2#4
  \fi
}
```

that type sets a sequence with the given generating function i.e.

```
$\seq{3}{,}{\n}{n}$
$\seq{4}{,}{\n}{}$
$\seq{3}{,}{\sqrt{\n}}{}$
$\seq{3}{/}{\frac{1}{\n}}{\frac{1}{n}}$
```

is equivalent to

```
$1, 2, 3, ..., n$
$1, 2, 3, 4, ...$
$\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, ...$
$\frac{1}{1}/ \frac{1}{2}/ \frac{1}{3}/ .../ \frac{1}{n}$
```

Although it works as intended, it fails when it's in an environment that supports alignment and is passed an alignment tab character (`&`) as it's second argument and the forth argument is empty i.e.

```
\begin{align}
  \seq{3}{&&,}{\n}{n} % this works
  \seq{3}{&&,}{\n}{}  % this causes an error 
\end{align}
```

After tinkering with the code I came to the conclusion that the error is caused by the `\ifx` statement only when evaluating to `%empty` and being preceded by characters, as demonstrated by the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\testa[2]
{%
  \ifx\\#2\\
    %empty, evaluation causes error
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}

\newcommand\testb[2]
{%
  \ifx\\#2\\
    #1
  \else
    %full, evaluation causes error
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \testa{&}{n}    \\ %ok
  \testb{&}{}     \\ %ok
%
  \testa{&}{}     \\ %ok
  \testb{&}{n}    \\ %ok
%
  foo\testa{&}{n} \\ %ok
  foo\testb{&}{}  \\ %ok
%
  foo\testa{&}{}  \\ % causes error
  foo\testb{&}{n}    % causes error
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How can the conditional be changed to handle the alignment tab character?

If the question is to specific, let me know and I'll remove it.

EDIT: added `\usepackage{amsmath}` to example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to hide the `&` from the branch that is being skipped

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\useone#1{#1}
\newcommand\testa[2]
{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%%
    %empty, evaluation causes error
  \else
    \useone{#1}%%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\testb[2]
{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%%
    \useone{#1}%%
  \else
    %full, evaluation causes error
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \testa{&}{n}    \\ %ok
  \testb{&}{}     \\ %ok
%
  \testa{&}{}     \\ %ok
  \testb{&}{n}    \\ %ok
%
  foo\testa{&}{n} \\ %ok
  foo\testb{&}{}  \\ %ok
%
  foo\testa{&}{}  \\ % causes error
  foo\testb{&}{n}    % causes error
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Makes sense in retrospect, useone is not expanded if the branch is not executed right?

Comment: @user414064 yes which means that `&` is inside a `{}` so doesn't end the cell.